# Java program suddenly stops repainting and refuses to close

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, paintcomponent, repaint

I'm making a game, and it has a thread that basically repeatedly calls my game's update function and calls the component's repaint function (see below).

```
public void run()
{
    try {
        while(true)
        {
            b.infps++; //b is the JComponent that draws the game and also passes on the game's update steps

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
            if(start >= b.lastSec + 1000)
            {
                b.fps = b.infps;
                b.infps = 0;
                b.lastSec = start;
            }
            lastMil = start;

            if(!b.paused || b.step) //paused is when the game is paused, and step allows the game to update one frame at a time by keypress (for debugging)
            {
                b.update();
                b.step = false;
            }
            else
                b.updateWhilePaused();

            System.out.println("Running at "+Math.min(desired, Math.max(1, desired + start - finish)));
            b.repaint();
            long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Thread.sleep(Math.min(desired, Math.max(1, desired + start - finish)));
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
}
```

This has been working for over a year, but all of a sudden, I come across this bug, where it appears as if the whole thing freezes, no more repainting, and no more user interaction (can't even close the window with Alt+F4 or by pressing the red X).

At first I thought it was some infinite loop I'd created, but when I checked, the thread was still running fine and dandy, and calling both update and repaint every 24 milliseconds (System.out.println still repeatedly posts to eclipse's console).

Using Java VisualVM tool, I've tried analysing the change, and the only thing I can identify is that the AWT-EventQueue-0 stops alternating between running and waiting, and starts running constantly.

To draw my game, I've overrided the paintComponent method of "b", and I've identified that this is no longer being called, even though b.repaint() is. I've also checked to make sure that it is still in the JFrame's component hierarchy, which it is. (I had it print out b.getParentComponent() until it reached the JFrame, and nothing changes there).

So I'm baffled as to what's happening here.

Comment: Sounds like something is blocking your EDT. Possibly a tight loop.

Comment: A tight loop? Can you expand on that?

Comment: Do you use version control? If so, back up your code to your last usable version, and then see what changes have caused this to occur. If still stuck, I think that you'll want to create and post your [mcve] that illustrates your problem for us. This is not a complete code dump, but instead -- well read the link and you'll see.

Comment: It's a (usually) endless loop that has no sleep or other blocking operation in it. Something like `while (true) if (condition) statement;` - which will cause the thread never to be in waiting state (and eat up a lot of CPU). The fact that your `paintComponent` is never called indicates that the EDT is blocked. The fact that the EDT is always in running state indicates a possible tight loop.

Comment: @RealSkeptic So, the loop can in fact be a part of my code, and that'll prevent a repaint? Even though I'm calling repaint on a separate thread and that is running fine?

Comment: The supposed loop is somewhere in code that runs under the EDT - an event handler, an `invokeLater` runnable, or a `paint`/`paintComponent` of some component. Not necessarily related to the one you are repainting here.

Comment: Update: You're right, it was a loop, and running off the mouseDragged event. That explains everything, except for why the Java VisualVM didn't register that it was spending a lot of time there.. Unless it only prints back functions and their running time once they've finished executing?

For future reference, do either of you know anything I can do to identify where an infinite loop is located? Besides putting debug println's in every function.